# Updating instances with JPARepository using suggested updateAllBy method

Tags: sql-server, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'm implementing a method in order to update my ShipmentLine instances through their trackingNumber and I've noticed Hibernate suggests some update methods. I'm trying to figure out in which fashion are implemented and which parameters should take:

```java
public interface ShipmentLineRepository extends JpaRepository<ShipmentLine, ShipmentLinePK> {
    void updateShipmentLinesByTrackingNumber(String oldTrackingNumber, String newTrackingNumber); //Not sure about how many params takes
}
```

What I'm trying to do is find all ShipmentLine by their current trackingNumber and update them with the new one.

BTW: I'm querying against a SQL Server database.

Comment: No idea what your question. How would we know what parameters your method should take?

Comment: @Dale K. This is just what I'm asking about. Since the method is suggested by JPARepository Interface, I'm assuming it's being implemented too, but I'm not given any clue about which parameters should it take.

Comment: Have you read the official documentation? What generated the `updateShipmentLinesByTrackingNumber` method, its clearly specific to your project, so you must have access to its definition?

Comment: @Dale K Forget about ShipmentLine, it's just an attribute in my model: I could have wrote down companyId, volumeShipment, whatever. The point is why jpa repository suggests me methods like void updateAttributeOfYourModel() and, since that, which is their implementation? It is something clearly beyond my specific project (Well, unless I'd invented the update method on the relational ddbb without being aware of that...) I'm only able to find SimpleJpaRepository class which implements only the very basic CRUD methods, not the more complex ones.